# SQLite database locked - Python Flask on Ubuntu Docker writing to Azure mounted file share

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, docker, flask, azure-web-app-service

I've built a React SPA running through Flask server and python API in Ubuntu on docker image.

Developing locally on Windows SQLite works perfectly. However, when I deploy the docker container to Azure Web App - and set the path to a mounted file share - the DB file has zero size and throws locked error.  Python successfully writes a text log file to the mounted share - so I've verified permissions etc.

When I write the DB into /home/site this error doesn't occur. But then I don't have the DB in persisted storage.

Has anyone encountered anything similar to this?  I wondered about the awful hack of copying the DB file onto the mounted share, but for obvious reasons, this makes my skin crawl ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure Storage mount, make sure you're using files container instead of blob as blob is [read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage#limitations-of-azure-storage-with-app-service). Also make ensure that the path in your docker image matches the path of mount.

[image: azure storage mount]

Let me know if doc linked above or this troubleshooting [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems) doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. An empty file is being created, so RW access is ok. It's perhaps something to do with latency - a file lock being held when the DB create process runs. Have't progressed this.